# Drag and drop controls at runtime in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, drag-and-drop

We have requirement in our application to create template pages at run time. For this we need to have a feature like form designer in ASP.NET to be built. Facility to drag the controls from toolbox and drop in the form at runtime should be made available to the user. Solution should be in pure ASP.NET. Silverlight is not being used in the application. Please suggest a best way to achieve this requirement.

Comment: IMHO: If you want someone to desgin asp.net pages, give them visual studio. Why reinvent the wheel? You could create your own visual studio shell if required.

Answer (score 1):

Enable draggable functionality on any DOM element. Move the draggable object by clicking on it with the mouse and dragging it anywhere within the viewport.

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: This seems promising. Can you elaborate on a solution, please?